# How to get ALB oidc header in service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I have configure OIDC authentication action in ALB rules as follow.
/ui/* -> authenticate then forward (this is my angular app)
then I configure multiple path to java micro service as follow without authenticate.
/api1/* then forward to TG1
/api2/* then forward to TG2

I am not getting oidc header in service as mentioned in ALB document.
Do i need to authenticate each api path to get those header?